# How to sort or filter JSON data by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

So I finally got star wars API to display the names of each character from the "people" object this JSON array taken from https://swapi.co/api/people/ in Vanilla Javascript. I need to, however, sort or filter the data results based on the specific value which is https://swapi.co/api/species/1/ the current code I have, when I run it displays the table with the names of all species of people, I only need the human species. Here is my code:

```js
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/?format=json';

function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

function constructTableRow(data) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    const {
        name,
        height,
        mass,
        hair_color
    } = data;
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
    return row;
}

function constructElement(tagName, text, cssClasses) {
    const el = document.createElement(tagName);
    const content = document.createTextNode(text);
    el.appendChild(content);
    if (cssClasses) {
        el.classList.add(...cssClasses);
    }
    return el;
}

const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then((data) => {
    data.results.forEach(result => {
        const row = constructTableRow(result);
        swTable.appendChild(row);
    });
});
```

```html
<table id=sw-table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

The JSON endpoint come from https://swapi.co/api/people/

How do I get the table to only display the data for only the human species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned by the species API includes a `people` array. So instead of filtering `people`, loop over the people array.

However, this could cause a problem due to the SWAPI [rate limiting](https://swapi.co/documentation#rate).

```js
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/?format=json';

function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

function constructTableRow(data) {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  const {
    name,
    height,
    mass,
    hair_color
  } = data;
  row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
  row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
  row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
  row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
  return row;
}

function constructElement(tagName, text, cssClasses) {
  const el = document.createElement(tagName);
  const content = document.createTextNode(text);
  el.appendChild(content);
  if (cssClasses) {
    el.classList.add(...cssClasses);
  }
  return el;
}

const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

fetchData(url).then(data =>
  data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
    fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
      const row = constructTableRow(result);
      swTable.appendChild(row);
    })
  )
);
```

```html
<table id=sw-table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also when I add .sort() to the name, it breaks. Do I have to make a separate function to sort alphabetically?

Comment: There's no array of names to sort. `data.people` is an array of URLs. So it's not clear what you're trying to sort.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what about using `filter`?

```
const humansOnly = result.filter(p => p.species.indexOf('https://swapi.co/api/species/1/') !== -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that `https://swapi.co/api/species/1/` is human, so you can just check to see if that url exists in the `species` array using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const isHuman = guy=>~guy.species.indexOf('https://swapi.co/api/species/1/');
```

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to determine an element exists in an array. It returns negative one if it does not exist, so using [`bitwise NOT (~)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) makes it truthy if it exist and falsey if it doesn't by turning a -1 into a zero.

Then you can filter your results on that function before looping them..

```
data.results.filter(isHuman).forEach(result => {....});
```

```js
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/?format=json';

function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

function constructTableRow(data) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    const {
        name,
        height,
        mass,
        hair_color
    } = data;
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
    return row;
}

function constructElement(tagName, text, cssClasses) {
    const el = document.createElement(tagName);
    const content = document.createTextNode(text);
    el.appendChild(content);
    if (cssClasses) {
        el.classList.add(...cssClasses);
    }
    return el;
}

const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

const isHuman = guy=>~guy.species.indexOf('https://swapi.co/api/species/1/');

fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then((data) => {
    data.results.filter(isHuman).forEach(result => {
        const row = constructTableRow(result);
        swTable.appendChild(row);
    });
});
```

```html
<table id=sw-table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

And *another* example using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (in place of detecting an negative index):

```
fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then(data => {
    data.results
        .filter(person => person.species.includes("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"))))
        .forEach(human => swTable.appendChild(constructTableRow(human)))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
    fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then((data) => {

       data.results.forEach(result => {
       const row = constructTableRow(result);
       if(result.species === "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/") {
           swTable.appendChild(row);
        }
   });
```